# HTML Form sends data to PHP Form without leaving the current page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having issues with sending data from my HTML Form to my PHP page (via JS/AJAX) while staying on my current page.  Here is what I currently have in place:

HTML Section:

```
<!-- Begin the Form --> 

<form id="signup-form" method="POST">

<!-- Input of E-Mail --> 

<div class="seven columns">

           <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail">

</div>

<!-- Send Button -->

<div class="five columns">

            <button name="submit" type="button" class="button">Subscribe</button>

</div>

<!-- End of the Form --> 

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'MCAPI.class.php';

$apikey = 'XXXXXX';
$list_id ='XXXXXX';

$api = new MCAPI($apikey);
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo "Email: ".$email;

$merge_vars = array(' ');
// By default this sends a confirmation email - you will not see new members
// until the link contained in it is clicked!
$retval = $api->listSubscribe( $list_id, $email, $merge_vars );

if ($api->errorCode){
echo "Unable to load listSubscribe()!\n";
echo "\tCode=".$api->errorCode."\n";
echo "\tMsg=".$api->errorMessage."\n";
} else {
echo "E-Mail submitted to the pxCollective Newsletter!";
}
?>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();

if(email=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "subscribeEmail.php",
    data: email,
    success: function(){
    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
    });
}
return false;
});
 });
 </script>
```

If I don't try to keep it on the current page with JS/AJAX it'll direct to the PHP page just fine and subscribe the user to the mailing list.  Any ideas as to what my issue may be?

Thanks!

Comment: `data` should be a key/value object pair, I think. Have you tried `data: {'email': email}`?

Comment: I've tried using the ' ' and the suggestions by Alon & Elton but neither fixes my issue.  It's almost like the button click is not being caught.  Is there a way I can print out logging information in the PHP page to a text file?  Since I'm not even getting my emails saying I've signed up for newsletter I'm thinking we aren't making it into the PHP page.  

Thoughts?

Comment: Try `file_put_contents('log.txt', 'Something I want to log');`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line `data: email,` should be `data: {email: email},`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            var email = $("#email").val();

            if(email=='')
            {
                $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "subscribeEmail.php",
                    data: {email: email}, // don't data: email,
                    success: function(){
                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$('.submit').click()`, but there is no element with class `submit`! Your submit button is class `button` instead.

You *should* use `$('#signup-form').submit()` instead and change your `<button>` to an `<input type="submit">`.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "subscribeEmail.php",
data: {email:email},
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
```

It should be "email="+email